# peer node unable to create chaincode container - dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied error

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to setup hyperledger network on centos

Using 1.1.0 images from ibmblockchain docker hub.

I am able to start up the network without any issues. that is 1 orderer, 3 kafkas, 3 zookeepers and 2 peers.

But every time i try to instantiate chaincode, I see the below error in the peer docker containers. Can anyone help me with this issue.

2018-07-19 19:05:30.570 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> ERRO 3ac start-could not recreate container , because of Post http://unix.sock/containers/create?name=dev-peer1.bns-250A-v1.0.2-b3: dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
2018-07-19 19:05:30.570 UTC [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU 3ad container lock deleted(dev-peer1.bns-250A-v1.0.2-b3)
2018-07-19 19:05:30.570 UTC [chaincode] launchAndWaitForRegister -> DEBU 3ae stopping due to error while launching: Post http://unix.sock/containers/create?name=dev-peer1-chaincode1-v1.0.2-b3: dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
error starting container.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is a permission issue with `/var/run/docker.sock`.

Check your `/var/run/docker.sock` permission.

`ls -l /var/run/docker.sock` will let u know if you have the correct .permission

`sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock` should give it correct rw access.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by adding Username, UserID and GroupID permissions to the docker run command.

Ex:

peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: ibmblockchain/fabric-peer-$ARCH:1.1.0
    environment:
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=composer_default
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      - USERNAME=(your userid)
      - USER_ID=1000
      - GROUP_ID=999

This is mentioned as the solution in ibmblockchain github repo :
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibm-blockchain-issues/issues/125

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Grpc FUSE from docker desktop for macos did the work for me.

You will find it settings > General >